# Particular solution of a higher order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently solving this higher order DE
$$16y''''+8y''=-1$$
I got the complementary solution as
$$y_c=C_1+C_2x+C_3\cos\frac{\sqrt2}{2}x+C_4\sin\frac{\sqrt2}{2}x.$$
Now onto the particular solution, I start with
$$g(x)=-1, \{1\}$$
$$y_p=A1$$
$$y_p'=y_p''=y_p'''=y_p''''=0$$
$$\implies 16(0)+8(0)=-1,$$
which doesn't even make sense. I'm guessing that $$g(x) = -(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$$
because when I plugged the DE in Wolfram, it gave me a particular solution of functions of sine and cosine. However, I couldn't  work out the solution. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Remember what happens when your basis for the particular solution is not linearly independent from the complementary?

Comment: Oh! That's right!

Comment: As a check the correct particular solution is $-\frac{1}{16}x^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RHS is constant so $y(x)$ can atmost ne a 4th degree polynomial, take $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ and insert it in the ODE $$16y''''(x)+8y''(x)=1$$ to get
$$16(24a)+8(12ax^2+6bx+2c+d)=0=-1 \implies a=0, b=0, d=0,  c=-\frac{1}{16}.$$ So the particular integral (solution) is
$$y=-\frac{1}{16}x^2+e$$, Finally the constant $e$ will merge with $C_1$ in your C.F. So the total solution is $$y(x)=C.F-\frac{1}{16}x^2.$$ You have already found C.F.